# 'Customer email is required' error while checking out as guest

Tags: magento-1.9

I am getting an error **'Customer email is required'** when clicking on Place Order button while checking out using guest account. 
How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Thought you checkout as guest magento store your information in customer table,
so It is compulsory to customer to enter `email` though it is a guest checkout.

Comment: Yes email field is required and i am adding email on billing form.

Answer (score 0):

This suggests that the email attribute isn't being saved correctly.

You haven't mentioned whether 
it's flagged in an in-page validation (i.e. the field is highlighted), or

in a post-process error message (the page reloads and an error message is displayed).

These two circumstances would require vastly different solutions.

Comment: On clicking Place Order button it calls onepage controllers saveOrder function using ajax and on return popup shows with text Customer Email is required.

Comment: If order for better debugging, you'll need to provide much more detailed information.

 We'll need to know if you are using any custom or third-party checkout modules, and if any attribute modification has happened during the production of the store. 

This could also be an issue with the template, so I'll try and cover all bases in my answer.